# Excel - Error if certain percent of cells is blank

Tags: excel

- I have 10 cells (A1-A10) in my workbook where I can enter values
- I have 1 cell (C4) where average of that value is displayed with formula: `=AVERAGE(A1:10)`
- I have 1 cell (C5) where this average is rounded to certain number with formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(C4+MIN(ABS(A1:A10-C4)),A1:A10,0)),C4-MIN(ABS(A1:A10-C4)))`

What I need is cell C4 and C5 to show error text if more than 25% of A1-A10 cell values are missing.

So if 2 values are missing it should display a number by using that formula but if 3 are missing it should display some error text.

I can't use UserForm's because its a huge document. Any chance to do this with simple workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385) should be able to handle a count of  true blanks as well as zero-length strings left by formulas.

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:A10)<3, IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(C4+MIN(ABS(A1:A10-C4)),A1:A10,0)),C4-MIN(ABS(A1:A10-C4))), "show error text")
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! Is there any way to add (red) color to that field? Probably not.

Comment: There are some ways to determine a cell's color, typically over-complicated and rarely worth it although XL2013 makes it a little easier I believe. If the color comes from a Conditional Formatting rule (and why shouldn't it...?) it is easier to duplicate the logic in the rule.